# R Interpolation of previous days using total value

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm, new to data science methods so this is probably a basic question.

I have a dataset with daily observations but sometimes I get missing values for a couple of days and then an accumulated value for all the missing days. I know that total value is correct and I need (or, at least, it would be preferable, if possible) to use it to interpolate all those missing data.

This is a dummy example of the dataset I'm working with:

`data <- data.frame(time=c(1:10), value=c(22,15,24,28,NA,NA,87,18,22,24))`

Using the mean for the three days is not really an option since it is extremely rare for two days to have the same exact value, let alone consecutive days.

Is there any way to interpolate those days using the accumulated value or would I need to drop that observation and interpolate three days using something like splines, time series methods (SARIMA models) or neural nets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: We could fill in blanks using an average calculated with the "total." I understand you are looking for something fancier since flat readings are rare, but it's not clear from your description what specific pattern would be more likely. If you want it to look more plausible, you could add some noise to it...

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(!is.na(lag(value)))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(value2 = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE) / n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value2)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3)
```

[image]

---

The `approx` function will handle linear interpolation:

```
data2 <- as.data.frame(approx(data$time, data$value, xout = 1:10))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(time, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = data2, aes(x, y), shape = 21, size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: The 87 in OP's question represents the _aggregate_ of value for t=5,6,7. They are after something that interpolates from t=4 to t=8 such that the sum of t=5,6,7 is (close to) 87 -but notes that a simple average is not desirable either.

Comment: But the thing is that 87 is the value for all three days, so I would need to kind of 'share it' between the missing value days and the day when it was observed. They all should be around the 20's or 30's mark like the other values.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I'll give it another go.

Comment: Thank you so much! I like the noise addition. About the pattern, that is what I'm trying to do, but in order to get a proper model I need to 'fix' this observations, otherwise the model doesn't even recognise seasonal trends which are clearly there.

Comment: Perhaps a next step could be to summarize seasonality based on the reliable measurements, and then apply an adjustment to your imputed values based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this with the approximated values re-apportioned based on the multi-day aggregates:

(I added a little extra made-up data to include a second run of NAs plus an aggregate.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(time = c(1:14), 
                   value = c(22, 15, 24, 28, NA, NA, 87, 18, 22, 24, NA, NA, 65, 20))

# Possible approach
data2 <- data |> 
  mutate(to_share = if_else(is.na(value) | is.na(lag(value, default = 1)), value, 0),
         to_model = if_else(to_share == 0, value, NA_real_),
         interpolated =  approx(time, to_model, xout = time)$y,
         interpolated = if_else(is.na(to_model), interpolated, NA_real_),
         group = if_else(!is.na(to_model), 1, 2),
         group = cumsum(group != lag(group, default = first(group)))
         ) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(sum_interpolated = sum(interpolated)) |> 
  fill(to_share, .direction = "up") |> 
  mutate(interpolated = interpolated / sum_interpolated * to_share,
         new_value = coalesce(interpolated, value)) |> 
  ungroup()

data2 |> 
  ggplot(aes(time, to_model)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y = interpolated), shape = 21, size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>